# Slow dynamic layout in ETO Forms

Tags: c#, layout, eto

I am trying to make a dynamic layout in Eto Forms that has two columns that are split 50/50. 
It seems like the default behavior is to give the last control in a row the remaining space. I then created an event handler that resizes the controls to 1/2 of the canvas width. This works (see Figure) but is slow when the window is resized. It looks like the redraw is lagging behind a few milliseconds and thus parts of the canvas are black.
Is there a better way to do this in ETO?

[image: Two columns of controls]

I am pasting my code below. The window has about 20 controls that I reduced to 2 for clarity in the code below.

```
public class MyLayout : DynamicLayout
{
 public CheckBox PeopleIsOn = new CheckBox() { Text = "On/Off" };
 public Label PeopleLabel = new Label { Text = "People" };

 public MyLayout(){
 PeopleIsOn.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                PeopleLabel.Width = Width / 2;
                Invalidate();
            };
        this.BeginVertical();

        this.BeginHorizontal();
        this.Add(PeopleLabel);
        this.Add(PeopleIsOn);
        this.EndHorizontal();

        this.EndVertical();
}
}
```

In WPF this could be achieved easily with the `<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />`. Is there an equivalent in Eto.Forms?

Comment: cant you use a tablelayout instead?

Comment: I think tables have the same issue. The cell width is autosized or some fixed value. Making a 50/50% column layout that resized on SizeChanged would require the same code and it is also slow.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using TableLayout instead of DynamicLayout, and it works for me.

```
public class MyLayout : TableLayout
{
    public CheckBox PeopleIsOn = new CheckBox() { Text = "On/Off" };
    public Label PeopleLabel = new Label { Text = "People" };

    public CheckBox OtherIsOn = new CheckBox() { Text = "On/Off" };
    public Label OtherLabel = new Label { Text = "Other" };

    public MyLayout()
    {
        this.Rows.Add(new TableRow(
            new TableCell(PeopleLabel, true), // the true argument of TableCell is important in the cells of the first row
            new TableCell(PeopleIsOn, true)
        ));
        this.Rows.Add(new TableRow(
            OtherLabel, // from second row the parameter is no longer needed
            OtherIsOn
        ));
    }
}
```